# Have checkbox displayed as checked based on query

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013, is there a way to have a checkbox display as checked based on a query? I have searched everywhere and haven't found an answer. I need to have the checkbox display as checked if the record is in the query results, otherwise it stays unchecked.

I know there is probably a simple answer to this, but I just can't find the right combination of words to unlock the answer from Google. :)

Thanks!

Edited to add SQL of query I want to bind the checkbox to:

```
SELECT DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI, DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZONE_NAME, DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZATTRIBUTE_NAME, Format([ZATTRIBUTE_VALUE_STRING],"True/False") AS ZATTRIBUTE_VALUE
FROM DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue INNER JOIN WELL_MASTER ON DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI = WELL_MASTER.UWI
WHERE (((DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZONE_NAME)="NFX_HEADER") AND ((DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZATTRIBUTE_NAME)="NFX_OBO_WELL"));
```

CPerkins, I hope this is what you are asking for. It's the expression code for the checkbox I am having trouble coming up with. I was hoping all I had to do was add the name of the query and column to the checkbox, but it isn't that simple. This is what I have:

```
[qry_OBO_WELLS]![ZATTRIBUTE_VALUE]
```

I apologize if this seems like a dumb question, but I'm self-taught, so there are large holes in my education in Access programming. I appreciate you taking the time to help with this.

Comment: Are you familiar with bound controls?  You can bind a checkbox control to a Boolean field (a.k.a. Yes/No or True/False field).  If this is not what you mean, you need to provide a bit more detail since what you describe sounds a bit odd to me.  If a record is NOT in the query results, then it will not be displayed on a form or report at all.  That means such a checkbox as you describe will always be checked because only records in the query will be displayed.  Instead, do you mean another query different from the main form/report's query?

Comment: Yes, I've created a separate query specifically for the checkbox.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311885/sql-as-control-source-for-access-form-field.  The key idea is to bind the checkbox control to an expression that executes the query in some way.  But if you post the primary record source query (of the form/report) and the supplemental query you want as the checkbox source, perhaps there are more specific, efficient solutions.  (Unless you want only vague, approximate, or even no answers then I would always post sample code or SQL even if you don't think the specifics matter at the time you ask.)

Comment: I added the code to the original question as well as more detail. Hope this helps.

Comment: In response to unlocking the answer in Google, I suggest always reviewing documentation first. In this case, search first for `access checkbox control source` and you'll get [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/checkbox-controlsource-property-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I'll admit that it's not clear that you **cannot** bind to a separate SQL statement. Rather, binding to a "table, query, or SQL statement" implies the _Record Source of the form/report_. You can only set a control source to a single field or VBA expression (see link in previous comment).

Comment: 1) Is `ZAttribute_Value` a Boolean (yes/no) value?  2) How do the query rows relate to the primary recordset--via the UWI column?  Without answering these two questions, exactly which value you want to represent with the checkbox is indeterminate.  There must be some method of choosing/filtering which row of the query is meant to represent the single yes/no value of the checkbox.  If instead you want the checkbox to represent the status of any/all the rows, then you need to have some kind of aggregate expression that boils down the multiple rows into a single Boolean value.

Comment: ZAttribute_Value is not a booleen, but rather a field in a linked table that contains a "Y" if the well is an OBO well. Yes, they are related on the UWI. It didn't matter what the value was, only if the query returned a record (hope that makes sense). If the query returned a record for a UWI, then the checkbox should be checked.

Comment: I was able to create the following expression which returns all records containing "NFX_OBO_WELL" as the ZAttribute_Name: `IIf([DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue]![ZATTRIBUTE_NAME]="NFX_OBO_WELL",1,0)` If I can figure out how to join two tables in the expression builder, I think I can come up with a solution. Any help with the join would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just discovered I was standing up in a canoe, trying to do this the hard way.

After thinking about what CPerkins had posted, I went back to my form query and added the table I wanted to use for the checkbox. I then used the IIf statement I posted in the comments for the OBO_WELL field. I then tied the checkbox to the OBO_WELL field, and it worked.

Thank you, CPerkins, for all of your help. :)

Comment: Great!  It sounds like you got the gist of my long answer before I was finished posting.  Of course I did not know the details of your table structure or primary query so that makes may answer probably much more complicated than needed.  It was good you could just include your simple field in your primary query.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to bind a control--in this case a checkbox--to an SQL expression.  For purposes here, I'll call this the secondary query to distinguish it from the primary query bound to the form/report.  Depending on conditions like 1) the size of the primary recordset bound to the form/report, 2) whether or not the primary query must remain updatable, and 3) the efficiency of the secondary SQL query, for instance whether it is based on indexed values, etc.  Here I outline two approaches.

**Executing a query directly for each record**

The basic approached is already outlined in [SQL as Control Source for Access Form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311885/sql-as-control-source-for-access-form-field) since a Checkbox is like any other control.  However, that question and the answers focus on a narrow approach of only getting the values.

Since you already have a saved query AND you only need to test for existence of returned record, then you could use the domain aggregate function.  Set the Checkbox.ControlSource property to

```
=DCount("UWI","qry_OBO_WELLS","UWI = " & [UWI])
```

This assumes that the primary form/report has a key field called [UWI] which will be passed to the aggregate function.

If you need to execute an unsaved query, you can craft your own VBA function and then call it in a similar fashion.  Just make sure to pass in the key values need to select the proper values.  Set the Checkbox.ControlSource property to

```
=GetCheckBoxValue([UWI])
```

which refers to your customer VBA function

```
Public Sub GetCheckBoxValue(vUWI as Variant) As Boolean
    GetCheckBoxValue = False 'Set default return value

    If IsNull(vUWI) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim rs As RecordSet2
    '* Only TOP 1 is required to test for existence of records
    Set rs = CurrentDB.Openrecordset( _
       "SELECT TOP 1 [qry_OBO_WELLS].UWI FROM [qry_OBO_WELLS]" & _
       " WHERE [qry_OBO_WELLS].UWI = " & vUWI
    If Not rs.EOF Then
      GetCheckBoxValue = True
    End If
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Here I am assuming that UWI is numeric.  If it is a string value, you need to take proper care to inject it into the SQL query properly, but using quotes and possibly SQL parameters.

The downside to this approach is that it must repeatedly open and close a new recordset object (and database connection) for each primary record.  This can be slow if processing many records.  It is possible to reduce that with some clever code to open and close connection and records once, but that's beyond scope of this answer.

**Include the secondary query as part of the form/report record source**

Either of the following alternative queries should be more efficient that binding to a separate query at the control level.  But both of those approaches can make the query non-updatable, which could effectively nullify an editable form.  It's not possible to predict or discuss here all the conditions that make a query updatable or not, so you would just have to test each.

With either query, the CheckBox can be bound to the query column as any other, like `CheckBox.Control Source = [CheckBoxValue]`

Join the primary query to the secondary query.  Set the form/report record source to the combined SQL statement.

```
SELECT Primary.UWI, Primary.OtherData, (Secondary.records) > 0 AS CheckBoxValue
FROM Primary INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Count(DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI) As records
    FROM DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue INNER JOIN WELL_MASTER ON DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI = WELL_MASTER.UWI
    WHERE (((DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZONE_NAME)="NFX_HEADER") AND ((DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZATTRIBUTE_NAME)="NFX_OBO_WELL")))
   AS Secondary
   ON Primary.UWI = Secondary.UWI
```

Or you could include a parameterized query as separate column.  This is more likely to preserve the updatability of the other primary query columns, but may not be as efficient as the SQL join statement above:

```
SELECT Primary.UWI, Primary.OtherData, 
    ((SELECT Count(DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI) As records
        FROM DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue INNER JOIN WELL_MASTER ON DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI = WELL_MASTER.UWI
        WHERE ((DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZONE_NAME="NFX_HEADER") AND (DBA_WellZoneIntrvlValue.ZATTRIBUTE_NAME="NFX_OBO_WELL")
          AND WellZoneIntrvlValue.UWI = Primary.UWI ))
   >) 0 As CheckBoxValue
FROM Primary
```